# Function whose tangent line intersection with x axis is equidistant from the origin and contact point

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Doing some calculus problems, I came across  quite a peculiar one. As the title says, the problem is as follows:

> Find a function whose tangent line intersection with $x$ axis is equidistant from the origin and contact point of the function and the tangent line.

It's a really interesting problem but I just can't grasp the solution. The only thing I managed to realize about this function is $y(0)=0$ ( provided it even is defined in zero ).

I've looked at polynomials ( the first foolish thought i had was "Hey, that has to be a parable" ), exponentials, xyperboles and even trigonometric function to try and construct any function with a similar behavior.

I just cannot write down the required differential equation, so I'm basically stuck, unable to find the function in question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT...The equation of the tangent to the curve $y=f(x)$ at the point $x=x_0$ is $$y-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$

Applying the information and the conditions given leads to $$x_0^2-\frac{2x_0f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}=f(x_0)^2$$

This is a differential equation which can be written as $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$$

Can you solve this?

Comment: Of course. Thank you.